# How to make class loader look in the provided JAR when looking for a class

Tags: java, jar, runtime

I am working with an embedded device that has JDK 1.4 installed. I want to use HttpClient (3.0.1) library to do client authentication via TLS.

My problem is that the device does not have all the JDK 1.4 classes installed, and it's specifically missing the ones dealing with certificates and SSL. So there are a lot of runtime `ClassNotFound` exceptions.

I have been able to resolve most of them by hunting down the missing class in the official JDK, adding them to a jar file and then providing the jar file to the device. 
But now I have hit a wall with certificate factory

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SystemClassLoader couldn't find java.security.cert.CertificateFactory
```

Even though the class is in the jar file that I provide, the loader can't find it. I believe the reason is because the device natively provides only 3 classes from the java.security.cert namespace (Certificate, CertificateEncodingException and CertificateException)

So even when I provide a jar with the missing class java.security.cert.CertificateFactory, the class loader only looks at its native namespace, doesn't find the class, doesn't bother to look any further.

I don't have access to the device to do anything besides providing jar files and classpath.
Is there a way to get the runtime loader to keep looking for the CertificateFactory class?

Comment: What kind of "device" specifically? What JRE is it using?

Comment: It's eWon Flexy, somewhere deep down there is a Linux distro. JRE is 1.4, with some device specific functions added (such as reading tags from industrial controllers)

Comment: The way to do this is to use a custom class loader. However, it turns out that the Wonka VM implementation doesn't let me load system classes (starting with "java.") with a non-system class loader :(